# Facebook Audience Network doesn't resolve

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I have the facebook audience network dependency in my list of dependencies. It used to work, but it stopped resolving for no discernible reason.

`compile 'com.facebook.android:audience-network-sdk:4.+'`

[image]

I'm not in offline mode.

**EDIT:**

Changing the build variant gives a more descriptive error message.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have a feeling they've pulled that version. For now fall back on the previous version:

```
compile 'com.facebook.android:audience-network-sdk:4.13.0'
```

Answer (score 1):

There was a problem with the POM file. Version 4.14.1 has been deployed with the fix. So you can now go ahead and use the latest version via gradle. Specifying 4.+ will automatically use the 4.14.1 version.